# Printing C++ code execution step by step

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

I have a project in windows in C++.
I am preparing a function level testing platform for the same and I want to process the C++ code in such a way that when the tests are run, every line of execution gets printed in a log file so that the code flow path can be revisited without any debuggers.
Is there any processing tool which will help me do that ? I am new to C++ so I don't know much about the available tools and Google didn't help much.

Even if you give me an idea about how I can develop one if its not already available, it'll be good.
My application is single threaded and a simple one. with several classes and around 30 functions. Load/Timing etc. are not a constraint. Preferably I'd like to print the locals and globals too at each line which gets executed. Somethign similar to how visual studio debugger helps us see everything at each step. I want that output in a file.

Comment: From what you have stated, I think you misunderstand the purpose of unit testing.

Comment: Log execution of each line? Are you sure it'll make your application debuggable? Really sure it's better than few, well placed, logs? BTW what's the connection between unit testing and logging?

Comment: OK I should call it function level testing. I guess in my organization everything other than integration test is called a Unit test :). Sorry about that.
Yes the logging will help. Writing a script to perform comparison with the last execution and the new one can give some good insight.

Comment: @UtkarshKumar That kind of information is available to the debugger ... printing it to a log file would be massive.  Additionally, you would have to decide what constitutes a "line":  e.g. a single assembly instruction, single line in your codebase?  Debuggers were created for this purpose ... use them.

Comment: @ZacHowland I agree with that. Are you aware of any debuggers which allow us to dump the entire locals at predefined points (which I can pinpoint in my code), via a command line so that they can be viewed later ?

Comment: @UtkarshKumar You can do all of that with most debuggers (e.g. GDB, VS), but only for a point in time (e.g. you can export the state at a given breakpoint).  Its usefulness is that it allows you to recreate the situation when debugging ... but I don't think that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok.. got it.. i'll try out what you mentioned nevertheless...wasn't aware of that. Thanks all for your inputs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were on Linux with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you could customize GCC (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), a domain specific language to extend GCC) by adding an internal pass which would change the gimple representation to e.g. add, inside each basic block and before each call, a Gimple call to some instrumenting routine. But that would take more than a week of work. Notice also that recent versions of the GDB debugger are scriptable in Python.

You could try to customize your compiler (or your IDE) likewise.

Otherwise, you probably want some [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Perhaps [AspectC++](http://www.aspectc.org/) could be useful. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331966/841108).

But I don't feel that it is related to [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). And whatever you try (which would magically instrument your code like you are dreaming of) would probably be much more complex and costly (in terms of effort) than plain testing techniques.

Perhaps just adding debug-printing macros inside your code is simpler. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502124/841108).