# Designing a C++ unintrusive event system

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, observer-pattern

I'm looking to implement an event system in c++, with which it would be possible for an object to react to another object's function calls. Every prototype I've seen on the Internet implements the observer pattern to create such an event system: a dispatcher singleton registers all objects who are interested in a particular event type, and the sender of the event has to explicitly send it. The downside of such an approach is that the sender knows that it's being listened to (it explicitly sends the event and thus the system is intrusive). If the sender wants all its hypothetical 2000 functions to be listened to, then it needs to call `dispatcher.post(my_event)` 2000 times, once from each of its functions.

I want to design a system where objects do not know that they're being listened to, where a hypothetical `StuffPerformer` class can have a `perform` function **without any event-related logic**, and a `Listener` class could have something like `coveted_function_or_perhaps_macro(StuffPerformer::perform, Listener::respond_to_perform)` in its constructor and thus successfully call `respond_to_perform` whenever a `StuffPerformer`'s `perform` function is called. In this situation `StuffPerformer` doesn't know that it's being listened to and doesn't need to change its logic; the system is unintrusive.

**I want to know** whether such a system is at all possible in c++, with or without compiler extensions (MSVC doesn't count) or third-party libraries. I guess this question can be boiled down to "Does standard c++ allow you to spot when a certain function is called?"

**One possible approach** is to write a template class `EventSendingFunction` that takes the event type and a lambda as template parameters and has an overridden `operator()` which posts the event to the dispatcher and then calls the lambda, and then use that class in place of regular c++ member function declarations. The problems are that it is still intrusive, but more bearable than having to write `dispatcher.post(event)` in the beginning of every member function, and that it will not be possible anymore to separate function declaration from definition (you cannot declare an object without a template parameter (the lambda) and fill it in later in another place).

Comment: Sure, after reflection, so long as you can give listened to classes a metatype.  Before that, nope.

Comment: gcc has ```-finstrument-functions``` option, but it will add hook to every function with/without some compile time annotation, which means that one have to decide which function need to be listened at compile time, or to implement some runtime judgement in user-provided hook function. I wonder if it's worth to give a try.

Comment: If you can survive with use special invoker to invoke ```StuffPerformer```'s instance method, actually there are some mechanism like [AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200183/) or [wrapper](https://stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf).

Comment: I was thinking that you could use the [Decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator) pattern to separate the event dispatch from the `perform` function. Herb Sutter talked about [metaclasses](https://herbsutter.com/2017/07/26/metaclasses-thoughts-on-generative-c/) at one point in time which could generate the event-handling system, probably in C++3x. Other than that, object-oriented systems and event-based systems are 2 different paradigms so maybe they don't belong together at all. Are you creating a solution looking for a problem?